# Find the value of k for a given limit

Tags: limits, trigonometry

If $f(x)=sin(2k - 3)x/4x$, fo $x < 0$, and $tan(3k - 4)x/2x$, for $x > 0$, and lim x tending to zero f(x) exists, then the value of k is given by  (piecewise function)

My work:

For lim to exist I put LHL= RHL but I am not able to solve the problem

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Rewrite $$\frac{\sin ((2 k-3) x)}{4 x}=\frac{(2k-3)}4\times\frac{\sin ((2 k-3) x)}{(2k-3) x}$$ $$\frac{\tan ((3 k-4) x)}{2 x}=\frac{(3k-4)}2\times\frac{\tan ((3 k-4) x)}{(3k-4) x}$$

I am sure that you can take it from here remembering that the limit of $\frac{\sin(y)}y= ??$ when $y\to 0$ and that $\frac{\tan(z)}z= ??$ when $z\to 0$.